# jQuery - Replace MyBB message but not some part of it

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, mybb

I am trying to replace some text. It will make sense if you continue reading.

```
[quote]Here is a message[/quote]
Message one

[quote]Another message[/quote]
Message two
```

The above is what is inside my **textarea**. I want to replace everyting except what is inside the quote-tags. I want to replace them like `[b]Message one[/b]` so it will add **[b]** and **[/b]** around the original message. The end result should look like this:

```
[quote]Here is a message[/quote]
[b]Message one[/b]

[quote]Another message[/quote]
[b]Message two[/b]
```

So basically exclude the [quote] and apply [b] and [/b] around the original message. I tried with some exclude regular expression, but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Would there always be a new line between the two ?

Comment: or maybe: `$("#userinput").val().split(/\n/).map(function(v){
    return v && !~v.indexOf('[quote]')?'[b]'+v+'[/b]':v;
}).join('\n');` http://jsfiddle.net/sG7DY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var string = "Replace this[quote]Here is a message[/quote]\nReplace this\n\n[quote]Another message[/quote]\nReplace this as well";
string.replace(/(\[\/quote\]\s*|^)([^[]+?)(\s*\[quote|$)/g, "$1[b]$2[/b]$3");

///// And we get:
// [b]Replace this[/b][quote]Here is a message[/quote]
// [b]Replace this[/b]
//
// [quote]Another message[/quote]
// [b]Replace this as well[/b]
```

See the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8ttK/) as well.

Comment: Great job. It works ALMOST perfectly. Is it possible you can remove the new line at the end? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/p8jzV/1/

Comment: Change `$("textarea").val()` to `$.trim($("textarea").val())`. [I updated your fiddle for you.](http://jsfiddle.net/p8jzV/4/)

Comment: Perfect. Now another issue (I guess). If you do more than one line, it will add the [b] and [/b] to those as well. Wouldn't it be possible to add the b-tag around the lines instead of applying them to each line?

Comment: That is not what I am seeing. Can you give an example?

Comment: Oh my bad! I was looking at the wrong page. My bad! Thanks a lot for the help - It works!